# Помогите перенести строки в массиве на новую строку в phpword

Tags: php, массивы, phpword

Добрый день!
Помогите перенести строки в phpword, 3 дня уже маюсь с этим вопросом
Класс для переноса строки `$survey_activity_1->addTextBreak();`
Варианты в \r \n 
 и прочим не действуют

Массив меняется постоянно в зависимости от выбранных вариантов. Собирается он в переменную `$podkategorii`

Пробовал через `$podkategorii = implode($survey_activity_1->addTextBreak(),$podkategorii);`, но он не срабатывает

$survey_activity_1 - формируется строка для всавки

Помогите решить проблему!

Спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте вместо \r\n использовать PHP_EOL

Comment: Не срабатывает(

Comment: Там вроде `<w:br/>` надо использовать. Заменить `PHP_EOL` на `<w:br/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Вот что нашёл в [оф. документации](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/553#issuecomment-112743470)

```
$text = "foo\nbar\nfoobar";
$textlines = explode("\n", $text);

$textrun = $section->addTextRun();
$textrun->addText(array_shift($textlines));
foreach($textlines as $line) {
    $textrun->addTextBreak();
    $textrun->addText($line);
}
```

То есть разбейте на массив, а потом идите по нему.